# Can i implement this shadow efffect using XML android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want this shadow effect on bottom of textview. I tried many times like using layerlist with oval shape
But nothing exactly this

[image]

Tried Background is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item  android:left="1dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"


    >
<solid android:color="#C4CAEA"></solid>
</shape>
</item>
    <item  android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"

            >
            <solid android:color="#4567AE"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

OUTPUT OF TRIED BACKGROUND 
[image]

**Q)** Is it possible to implement this shadow effect using XML